# Realtime database cpu usage %100

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whatever method I try, database will be locked.
the processor will be 100% for at least 5 minutes.
I used this data to log

Example Structure
there are at least 10 million records here

```
RoomName:
   playcount:
      user_id:
        proccess:
           value:
           time: 


123232132321312313443:
    gmc_10:
       xasdddfdsdffdsdfff:
          remove_begin:
              value: 1200
              timestamp: 9888439944
```

what I tried

1- I tried deletes nodes. I can't delete one nodes. because I can't read one nodes.

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child ("player_room").LimitToFirst(1).
```

Result : **cpu usage 100%**

2- I tried orderbykey and started at end_at

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child ("player_room").OrderByKey().StartAt("0").EndAt("100").LimitToFirst(1).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task=>{
```

Result: **Cpu usage %100**

3- I tried to export from the firebase console

Result :   **cpu usage 100%**

*how can i read any one nodes?
i want to read "**123232132321312313443**" wildcard nodes
Not important ordering, sorting, equals.
i want just read any nodes.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of 10 million nodes you're going to have a hard time reading that list, and can only read data if you know its exact path. So it is somewhat expected that the database will be at 100% capacity for a bit when you try to access that list. But I would expect it to eventually completely the operation, as long as you request a reasonable subset of the data. If that doesn't happen for you, add information about the exact error you get to the question or [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Aside from that: you might want to enable Firebase's nightly backups, and use those to locally determine the exact path of the specific node you want to read/delete from the online database.

Comment: I think I will use backups.